# NoReadAccessException - Read access is allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.2, android-gradle-2.2

**System/api Configuration**

```
Android studio version : 2.2.3
Gradle version : 2.2.1
Java version : 1.8
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
```

**Exception**

```
18:26:43 NoReadAccessException
         Read access is allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runReadAction())
         Details: Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 20,4,main] 700161407
         ; dispatch thread: false; isDispatchThread(): false
         SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 2.2#AI-145.3537739 Studio, eap:false, os:Windows 10 10.0, java-version:JetBrains s.r.o 1.8.0_76-release-b03,6,main] 1350276257
```

When i tried to run application, i got this issue, can anyone know what i do to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
      // your code here
 });
```